# Dbus communication for Unity 3D

Tags: qt, unity-game-engine, dbus

I want to exchange data between a qt application and an unity 3D application. How can I use Dbus to fulfil the above requirements.

Comment: Despite the debatable choice of dbus, what have you tried so far, have you checked the manual for dbus-sharp and libdbus for qt?

Comment: I want to use DBus compulsory.